# Elastic search index mapping updation

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, bigdata

I am  using ES-2.4.0
Indexed json :
 `{
    "_id": 1,
    "name": "Longsword",
    "description": "The Longsword can be wielded in one or two hands",
    "category": "Sharp"
}`

1.I have created an index and the default mapping is being created.
2.Now i am trying to update the mapping as suggested here.

Link : https://gist.github.com/nicolashery/6317643

Regarding **point 1 : i have not used any analyzer ;**
  Regarding **point 2 : i am using analyser "not_analysed" ;**

But it is not working .

**Question : Has ES-2.X stopped mapping updation facility if not how can i update the mapping  ?**

Note : While trying i am getting this error

> {
>       "error": {
>           "root_cause": [
>               {
>                   "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
>                   "reason": "Mapper for [name] conflicts with existing mapping in other types:\n[mapper [name] has different [analyzer]]"
>               }
>           ],
>           "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
>           "reason": "Mapper for [name] conflicts with existing mapping in other types:\n[mapper [name] has different [analyzer]]"
>       },
>       "status": 400
>   }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, changing mapping type of existing fields are not allowed **ES 2.x** onwards.

From the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/indices-put-mapping.html#updating-field-mappings)

> In general, the mapping for **existing fields cannot be updated**. There
>   are some exceptions to this rule. For instance:
>
> - new properties can be added to Object datatype fields.
> - new multi-fields can be added to existing fields.
> - doc_values can be disabled, but not enabled.
> - the ignore_above parameter can be updated.

You would have to first [delete the index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/indices-delete-mapping.html) and create a new one with new mapping. Also there is a minor typo, it is **not_analyzed**("z" not "s")

Comment: sorry for the typo . it's 'z' .